# Why can I not scrape the title off this site?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom, scraper

I'm using simple-html-dom to scrape the title off of a specified site.

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.pottermore.com/');

foreach($html->find('title') as $element) 
       echo $element->innertext . '<br>';

?>
```

Any other site I've tried works, apple.com for example.

But if I input [pottermore.com](http://pottermore.com), it doesn't output anything. Pottermore has flash elements on it, but the home screen I'm trying to scrape the title off of has no flash, just html.

Comment: What does `var_dump($html->find('title'));` output? Could you place said content in the OP (if not too long, sometimes simple-html-dom's output is)

Comment: perhaps pottermore has anti-scraping protections and you're getting back something other than html (e.g. nothing).

Comment: Perhaps the site is checking user agent strings and such?  Are you sure that the HTML is getting downloaded properly?

Comment: are you referring to this title ? http://assets.pottermore.com/site/css/registration/images/pottermore-logo-lrg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :)

```
$url = 'http://www.pottermore.com/';
$html = get_html($url);
file_put_contents('page.htm',$html);//just to test what you have downloaded
echo 'The title from: '.$url.' is: '.get_snip($html, '<title>','</title>');

function get_html($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; //browsers keep this blank.  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;U;Windows NT 5.0;en-US;rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return($result);
}

function get_snip($string,$start,$end,$trim_start='1',$trim_end='1')
{
    $startpos = strpos($string,$start);
    $endpos = strpos($string,$end,$startpos);

    if($trim_start!='')
    {
        $startpos += strlen($start);
    }
    if($trim_end=='')
    {
        $endpos += strlen($end);
    }
    return(substr($string,$startpos,($endpos-$startpos)));
}
```

Comment: cURL + doesn't solve the actual problem and that's finding out the page title.

Comment: Sorry, I've read you question properly now :(|) - see the edit above

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm still a bit confused though, as per what get_snip is really doing to fix the problem.

Comment: `get_snip()` is a function to get the text between <title> and </title> I've tested it and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm what others are saying, if you don't send a user agent string this site sends 403 Forbidden.

Adding this worked for me:

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;U;Windows NT 5.0;en-US;rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)

Answer (score 0):

The function `file_get_html` uses [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) under the covers. This function can pull data from a URL, but to do so, it sends a User Agent string.

By default, this string is empty. Some webservers use this fact to detect that a non-browser is accessing its data and opt to forbid this.

You can set `user_agent` in php.ini to control the User Agent string that gets sent. Or, you could try:

```
ini_set('user_agent','UA-String');
```

with `'UA-String'` set to whatever you like.